# cbind to already existing dataframe in csv

Tags: r

In my project folder, there is a csv file with 3 columns. (A, B and C)
There is a dataframe (df) in my R console with same columns.
Is there a way to cbind df to csv?

Here column A and B is same

For example

```
#csv file
A  B     C
1  Ca   trww
2  gf   dfsd
3  gh   fgdfg
```

```
df
A  B     C
1  Ca   new_trww
2  gf   new_dfsd
3  gh   new_fgdfg
```

new csv file should be

```
A  B     C          C1
1  Ca   trww      new_trww
2  gf   dfsd      new_dfsd
3  gh   fgdfg     new_fgdfg
```

Comment: do a merge, `merge(csv_file, df, by = c("A", "B"))`

Comment: here we have to read the csv file first right? Can we not write it to csv without reading it?

Comment: Yes, read the csv first and assign it to object `csv_file`